# How to split a time into hourly basis in php

Tags: php

In my database my values are stored as .....start time  6:00am and end time as 7:00pm. 
I want to display 6:00 am to 7:00pm data into hourly basis format as below
6:00am to 7:00am
7:00am to 8:00am 
8:00am to 9:00am and so on upto 7:00pm
Can any one please help me how to get the data from mysql and split those timings as above. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of below code you can print all 1 hour duration within a start time & end time

```
<?php
    $start_time = strtotime('3:00am');
     $end_time = strtotime('09:00pm');
     $time_slots = array();
     $time_slots[] = date('h:ia', $start_time);
     while ($start_time !== $end_time)
      {
          $start_time = strtotime('+60 minutes',$start_time);
          $time_slots[] = date('h:ia', $start_time);
     }

    for ($i=0; $i < count($time_slots); $i++) {
          if(isset($time_slots[$i+1])){
          echo $time_slots[$i]." to ".$time_slots[$i+1]."<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```